# How to preview a folder of white SVG files?

Tags: finder, preview

I have a folder full of white SVG icons, but preview shows them over a white background, and I can't find a way to easily preview them all. I saw Gapplin, but 1) I find it hard to believe an external application is necessary for such as simple task, and 2) it seems I'd need to open 100 windows and tab through them.

How can I preview all of my SVG files?

Comment: I'd love to have an answer to this! … :) — I just want to browse them in Finder like any other image, and have it on grey background. I'm looking into https://boxy-svg.com/ but that is not Finder.

Comment: It's not Finder, but also looking into this for fast `.svg` preview: https://www.widsmob.com/viewer

Answer (score 1):

Found [this:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7651257)

> You might want to try pressing option-space for Quicklook in full
>   screen. This seems to have a black, rather than white, background. The
>   drawback is that you cannot easily navigate through the files with the
>   arrow keys.

Answer (score -2):

Find a dark desktop background, or a dark window, and put it roughly in the center of the screen. Then drag your Finder window off to the side, and use Quick Look. It'll put it over a blurred background—which will be dark thanks to the dark desktop/window.

(Untested, but it should work)

Comment: Doesn't work for me, SVG preview in Quick Look has a white background.

Comment: Oh, darn. I forgot that it wouldn't do the transparent blurred background like PNG files.